# How to override/extend javascript handlers?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have several .js files, all attached to some page. The base one which I'm adding to master page is responsible for showing ajax loader animation when there's Ms Ajax' activity. Below is the part of code that does it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if (isSysDefined()) {
       var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
       if (prm) {
           prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
           prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
       }
   }
});

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
   $('#ajax-loader').show();
}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
   $('#ajax-loader').hide();
}
```

Now, I want to extend BeginRequestHandler and EndRequestHandler in a different file. If I will simply repeat code above but with different implementation of the handlers, obviously one of them will not fire.

How can I have both handlers executed? At the end of the "base" handler I could trigger some new event so then I will be able to bind() to it at later stage, but really - is that the only way? Cause it seems hackish (in a bad way)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, though still somewhat "hackish" - you need to store reference to the previous function then execute this reference in the new function.

In your external file, have such code:

```
var prevBeginRequestHandler = 0;
if (typeof BeginRequestHandler == "function")
    prevBeginRequestHandler = BeginRequestHandler;

window.BeginRequestHandler = function() {
    if (prevBeginRequestHandlero)
        prevBeginRequestHandler();
    alert("I am another function");
};
```

And same for the second function.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/2QzzP/).

Just one thing - make sure to include the file after the first declaration of the functions.